# Spring MVC - add attribute when redirect using browser - breaking from iframe for redirect

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, redirect, iframe

I have an iframe inside a jsp which is for processing payment using a third party payment provider.

When I get the response from payment provider, I use another jsp file just for breaking out of iframe (using javascript, as I could not find anything to do this in jsp, and probably there is no such way to do it in jsp AFAIK).

Now, the problem for me is the error scenario. When I receive some error from the payment provider, I want to display that on top of the page where I am redirecting to after breaking from iframe.

We use flash attributes for dispalying the error messages while doing redirect from spring mvc using `redirect:`.

But I am not sure how to do that when using a browser redirect.

One solution (Post/Redirect/Get pattern) I could think of is to append the error respone in the url which I am using in the redirect from breaking out of iframe.

But this would require changes to our jstl tag files and that will be different from the design of our existing code.

Can anyone point me to some better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using session variable.

So just added a session variable in controller, and before the view was passed on from the last controller, copied the session variable into the redirect flash attributes and then it worked. I know this may not sound good enough, but that's how I had to make it work.